# Chrome extension - using the filesystem API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, writefile

The filesystem API cannot be used by unpacked extensions, which is awfully great for development.

But then the real surprise came when I realized I can't use it also with my extension packed, because Chrome tells me it cannot find it in the store and is thus greyed out.

Is there any way to actually develop with the filesystem API then?

My goal, in case this is the wrong direction in the first place, is to write some text to a file when some events in the browser happen. The file should be rewritten, rather than creating a new file, which is why I can't use the downloads API.

Is there any way out of this conundrum?

Comment: Are you referring to [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem)? It's apps-only, not extensions.

Comment: So there is no practical way for me to make an extension for self-use that overwrites a file? shame

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling on the same issue - a decent solution is to use the `chrome.downloads` API to download the file in overwrite and incognito mode.

Overwrite will stop the automatic indices added to downloaded file names, and incognito makes the download invisible in the browser except for incognito windows.

The main shortcoming is that it is of course constrained to the user's downloads folder.